# Using Func type within C# application

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates, func

I have a C# application in which i'd like to use the `Func` type :

```
public static decimal rate(decimal a)
{
    return (a < 100) ? a * 3 : a * 2;
}
public static bool EstInfereiurA(decimal a)
{
    return a < 200;
}
public static Func<decimal, decimal> ratefunc = (a) =>
{
    return (a < 100) ? a * 3 : a * 2;
};

public static void Main() {
    decimal a; 
    Console.WriteLine("donner a = ");
    a = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine(" a est t il inférieur à 200 ? {0} ", EstInfereiurA(ratefunc.Invoke(a)));
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine(" a est t il inférieur à 200 ? {0} ", EstInfereiurA(rate(a)));
    Console.ReadKey();
 }
```

My example is working fine, however I need to know what are the advantages of the use of `Func` type, and which improves the readability of the code.

1. In which cases it is recommended to use `Func`?
2. What are its advantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases you will use Func if you need someone else to provide the functionality for you. Aa Farhad pointed out it's used for delegation. In your case the Func doesn't make sense over the static method. One use case would be if you wanted to deliver a default method and allow someone else to replace it with their own. The below code wouldn't make sense in a real application but it should at least give an example usage:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var n = 5m;

        Console.WriteLine(Executioner.GetRate(n)); // -> prints 15
        // provides a new method to be called
        Executioner.GetRateFunc = a => a * 2;
        Console.WriteLine(Executioner.GetRate(n)); // -> prints 10
    }
}

public static class Executioner
{
    private static decimal MyGetRate(decimal a)
    {
        return (a < 100) ? a * 3 : a * 2;
    }

    public static Func<decimal, decimal> GetRateFunc { get; set; }

    public static decimal GetRate(decimal a)
    {
        var f = GetRateFunc ?? MyGetRate;

        return f (a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can think of `Func` and also `Action` as easy shortcuts that are available for use in the .net framework. If you just need a delegate that receives some arguments and has a return value use Func if you just need one that doesn't have any arguments use Action.

You should mostly use Func if the delegate type you want to use does not have any specific meaning in the application. In other words if you want to specify that a bunch of methods do binary calculation then definitely create the delegate:

```
public delegate int BinaryCalculate(int a, int b);
```

This would make it clear that the method is to do a binary calculation and it is simply more readable. However, if the delegate you are creating is just there to serve a purpose and you don't really care what it is called or it would never be used more than once just use the shortcut made available to you in the framework.

Other than what I mentioned above, there are not any specific advantages or disadvantages in using one or the other in terms of efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

[Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is useful for being able to pass a function call (see also [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for lambdas which return void). They form a generic way to refer to a particular delegate, rather than having to explicitly declare and name each delegate as it's used. This is particularly useful for simplifying syntax into generically defined functions, such as those employed by Linq methods.

In general, calling a delegate is slightly slower than calling a function, so in your example, it would be better to declare ratefunc as a method. The biggest place to use Actions/Funcs is in Linq and as parameters when needing to execute code in some specific way (within a sort of transaction or within a specific thread, for example)